GitHub token not found when using VS Code / Metals
Background: I am a long time IntelliJ IDEA user. Recently I am a bit disapponted with Scala 3 support in this IDE and I would like to try VS Code + Metals.
When I try to open any of my SBT projects in VS Code / Metals, I am show following error:

unable to locate a valid GitHub token from Or(Or(GitConfig(github.token),Environment(GITHUB_USERTOKEN)),Environment(GITHUB_TOKEN))

My projects use sbt-github-packages and I have my GitHub token present in my .gitconfig file in [github] / token.
The token works fine when I use IntelliJ or SBT from a command line to build the project, but VS Code Metals imports are failing for me.
Is there something special I need to do so that SBT finds the token when used from Metals?
